# Can't save additional data on polymorphic model - Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, laravel-4

I have:

```
class Media extends Base{
    public function mediable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Offer extends Base{
    public function media()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Media', 'mediable');
    }
}
```

I'm doing this:

```
Offer::find(5)->media()->save(
    new Media(array(
        'name' => 'sasdfasdf'
    ))
);
```

Everythig is fine except that "name" is not being saved in the database. Other fields like mediable_id and mediable_type are being saved as expected.

Any toughts?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
$media = new Media;
$media->name = 'Some name';
Offer::find(5)->media()->save($media);
```

For some reason the other way does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your own settings in your model. Add this code to your Media model and you will be able to use your original method:

```
protected $fillable = array('name');
```

See: http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: That doesn't do the trick! That attribute only works when posting data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by posting data? This affects Model->fill(…) and thus it affects new Model(…).